# The issue is that the image is not moving to the left although the style of the image changes.

Tags: javascript

I want to move an image to the left and right when clicking on a button. The problem is that the image is not moving to the left although the style of the image is changing. I hope someone can help me.

```js
var imgObj;

var currentWidth = 1;
var speed = 50;
var direction;

function init() {
    "use strict";
    imgObj = document.getElementById('myImage');
    imgObj.style.position = 'relative';
    imgObj.style.left = '0px';
}

function moveRight() {
    "use strict";
    direction = 1;
    currentWidth += (speed * direction);
    imgObj.style.left = currentWidth + 'px';
}

function moveLeft() {
    "use strict";
    direction = -1;
    currentWidth += (speed * direction);
    imgObj.style.right = currentWidth + 'px';
}

window.onload = init;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Walking image</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <form>
        <img id="myImage" src="https://placeimg.com/900/600/animals?t=1515065784396g" />
        <input type="button" value="Rechts" onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='https://placeimg.com/900/600/animals?t=1515065867693';moveRight()" />
        <input type="button" value="Links" onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='https://placeimg.com/900/600/animals?t=1515065784397';moveLeft()" />
    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `moveRight()` changes the `left`, `moveLeft()` the `right` property -> _"When both `left` and `right` are defined, the position of the element is overspecified. When this is the case, the `left` value has precedence when the container is left-to-right; the `right` value has precedence when the container is right-to-left."_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't adjust both left and right. Just use one of them.

Here both buttons adjust the left value. One increases the value and the other decreases.

```js
var imgObj;

var currentWidth = 1;
var speed = 50;
var direction;

function init() {
    "use strict";
    imgObj = document.getElementById('myImage');
    imgObj.style.position = 'relative';
    imgObj.style.left = '0px';
}

function moveRight() {
    "use strict";
    direction = 1;
    currentWidth += (speed * direction);
    imgObj.style.left = currentWidth + 'px';
}

function moveLeft() {
    "use strict";
    direction = -1;
    currentWidth += (speed * direction);
    imgObj.style.left = currentWidth + 'px';
}

window.onload = init;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Walking image</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <form>
        <img id="myImage" src="https://placeimg.com/900/600/animals?t=1515065784396g" />
        <input type="button" value="Rechts" onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='https://placeimg.com/900/600/animals?t=1515065867693';moveRight()" />
        <input type="button" value="Links" onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='https://placeimg.com/900/600/animals?t=1515065784397';moveLeft()" />
    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The image doesn't move to the left because you have to change `imgObj.style.left`, not `imgObj.style.rigth`:

```js
var imgObj;

var currentWidth = 1;
var speed = 50;
var direction;

function init() {
    "use strict";
    imgObj = document.getElementById('myImage');
    imgObj.style.position = 'relative';
    imgObj.style.left = '0px';
}

function moveRight() {
    "use strict";
    direction = 1;
    currentWidth += (speed * direction);
    imgObj.style.left = currentWidth + 'px';
}

function moveLeft() {
    "use strict";
    direction = -1;
    currentWidth += (speed * direction);
    imgObj.style.left = currentWidth + 'px';
}

window.onload = init;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Walking image</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <form>
        <img id="myImage" src="https://placeimg.com/900/600/animals?t=1515065784396g" />
        <input type="button" value="Rechts" onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='https://placeimg.com/900/600/animals?t=1515065867693';moveRight()" />
        <input type="button" value="Links" onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='https://placeimg.com/900/600/animals?t=1515065784397';moveLeft()" />
    </form>

</body>

</html>
```